# Replace temporary table with with clause

Tags: sql, oracle, with-clause

in DB#1  I am creating table tC by joining table A with table B where table B includes a list of values inserted by a remote query from a different DB#2 (DB link).

```
create table tC  
as  
(
select ta.col3, tb.col4  
from  
    tA, tB  
where  
     ta.col1 = tb.col2
```

Now I need to write it without the use of table B and without DB links which means I somehow need to have table B as a with clause with values taken as input.

1. Select array of values from DB#2
2. Use the values to join with table A in DB#1 to create table C

I am using a script. Assuming I have the array of values in memory how do I create a with clause with list of values and column names and use it for the join?

something like:

```
with tB as (  
5, 8, 14  
2, 3, 17  
10, 1, 15  
),  
create table tC  
as  
select ta.col3, tb.col4  
from  
    tB, tA  
where  
     ta.col1 = tb.col2
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this might be what you want:

```
create table tC as 
    with tB as (
          select 5 as col1, 8 as col2, 14 as col3 from dual union all
          select 2, 3, 17 from dual union all
          select 10, 1, 15
         ) 
    select ta.col3, tb.col3  
    from tB join
         tA  
         on ta.col1 = tb.col2 ;
```

Given your sample data, I have no idea what `tb.col4` could be referring to, so I changed it to `tb.col3`.

In Oracle, the `with` is attached to the `select`, so it goes between the `create table` and the `select`.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server you can use this as a table:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    VALUES
        (5, 8, 14),
        (2, 3, 17),
        (10, 1, 15)
) t (c1, c2, c3)
```

If your case is with Oracle you can check if there is any similarity for something like this.

---

**Edit**

I was looking and found something similar for Oracle:

```
create type pseudo_table as table of number
\\
select * from table(pseudo_table(1,2,3)) t
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You want this like right?

```
WITH tbl1 AS (
    SELECT * FROM (
        VALUES
            (1, 4, 7),
            (2, 5, 8),
            (3, 6, 9)
    ) temp (c1, c2, c3)
),
tbl2 AS (
    SELECT * FROM (
        VALUES
            (1, 11, 12, 13),
            (2, 22, 23, 23),
            (3, 33, 34, 33)
    ) temp (c1, c2, c3, c4)
) Select tbl1.c3, tbl2.c4 FROM tbl1 JOIN tbl2 ON tbl1.c1 = tbl2.c1
```